# Chrome - How to open a link (html anchor) to a PDF on the local drive in a new tab

Tags: google-chrome, browser, pdf, web-application

I have the following setup:

- WebApp is running in a Chrome Browser V74
- Content contains links to local pdf files
  `<a href="file://local.pdf">Link to local PDF<a>`
- Chrome PDF Setting: Download file links instead of showing with internal viewer is activated
- Chrome Plugin "Allow File Downloads" is installed (Unblocks restriction for local files, otherwise it wouldn't work at all)

What happens is:

1. Clicking directly on the link downloads the PDF, which is fine.
2. Opening the link with "open in new tab" or pushing the middle mouse wheel, opens a new tab with following address inside: **about:blank#blocked**. No download is executed or PDF shown. The Page in this new tab is just blank.

**The question is now what can be done to enable the PDF download by opening the PDF link in a new tab?** I think Chrome is preventing this for security purposes. I have found this article in the chrome forum:

- https://support.google.com/chrome/forum/AAAAP1KN0B0k-9y57tme2E/?hl=en&gpf=%23!topic%2Fchrome%2Fk-9y57tme2E

Sounds like the same issue, but I am not sure.